# How do you install tidyverse on R server

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I am familiar with installing packages on R desktop, however I recently switched to R server. When I install tidyverse using `install.packages('tidyverse')` I get the following output:

```
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘curl’, ‘httr’, ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/curl_4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 673779 bytes (657 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 657 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/httr_1.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 158465 bytes (154 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 154 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rvest_0.3.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1129355 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/xml2_1.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 261081 bytes (254 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 254 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 712837 bytes (696 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 696 KB

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/noahsiegel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lxml2
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libxml-2.0 was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libxml2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libxml2-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libxml2_dev (Solaris)
If libxml-2.0 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libxml-2.0.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’
* removing ‘/home/noahsiegel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xml2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/noahsiegel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘xml2’, ‘httr’ are not available for package ‘rvest’
* removing ‘/home/noahsiegel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rvest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/noahsiegel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpf8BbBr/downloaded_packages’
```

Then when I try to activate tidyverse in my library I get this output:

`Error in library("tidyverse") : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’`

Which leads me to assume there is something different out the install process on R server that I am unaware of.

Thank you in Advance,

Noah

Comment: The error messages show you are missing system dependencies. There aren't things R can install for you. If you are using ubuntu. Using something like` apt-get install` for each of `libcurl4-openssl-dev` and `libxml2-dev`. The `library()` will only work if the `install.packages()` runs without error.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: Follow up: I was able to install tidyverse after individually installing all of its dependencies in ubuntu 18.04.